# Perl using set_bound in Test::MockObject

Tags: perl, unit-testing, testing, tdd

Can someone please provide an example of using `set_bound()` method from [`Test::MockObject`](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Test%3a%3aMockObject) module?

Can `set_bound()` method return an instance of [`Test::MockObject`](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Test%3a%3aMockObject) (or any other object for that matter)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

***"Can set_bound method return an instance of Test::MockObject (or any other object for that matter)"***

Yes. From the [source](http://cpansearch.perl.org/src/CHROMATIC/Test-MockObject-1.20110612/lib/Test/MockObject.pm):

```
sub set_bound {
    # ...
    return unless exists $bindings{reftype( $ref )};
    $self->mock( $name,  $bindings{reftype( $ref )} );
} # So this returns either undef, or result of mock() call

sub mock {
    #...
    $self;
} # So this CAN return an instance of Test::MockObject
```

***Can someone please provide an example of using set_bound method from Test::MockObject module?***

```
my $value = 'X';
$mock->set_bound( 'next_value', \$value );
is( $mock->next_value, 'X' );
$var = 'Y';
is( $mock->next_value, 'Y' ); # Method result changed to new value of the variable
```

Why use it? POD states "This is often handier than replacing mock methods". I guess "handier" is in the eye of the beerholder, but it certainly is a nice shortcut to have available.

Comment: You are absolutely right - I'm replacing the mock methods, but thanks for the example! :)